# Page switch in Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

I'm modifying a Tumblr theme. I have a page newsletter and only on this page I want to add a sign up form (hard coded).

Is it possible in Tumblr to see if the current page == 'newsletter' or something? Maybe by ID?

I know it is possible for posts but I need it for a page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A (slightly) safer solution/hack -

```
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Posts}{block:PostTitle}
<script>
    var postID = '{PostID}',
        postTitle = {JSPostTitle};

    if (!postID && postTitle === 'Name of your Newsletter Page') {
        // Tumblr custom "pages" have no post ID

        // Dynamically insert your HTML, or Dynamically "Show" a hidden element
    }
</script>
{/block:PostTitle}{/block:Posts}{/block:PermalinkPage}
```

Where `Name of your Newsletter Page` is the Page Title you assign your newsletter page on Tumblr.

Wrapping this `<script>` in `{block:PermalinkPage}...etc` ensures the script only renders on the right kinds of pages.

Then, to be safe we must then check this permalink page does ***not*** have a Post ID, so we don't accidentally match an actual *Post*.  The only other possibility for a permalink page with no Post ID is a custom tumblr Page, so it suffices to check the Page Title to some preset value.

In general, switching based on the `window.location` of a page is really *not* a good solution.

As for creating / showing the signup form -- I'd personally go with hard-coding the form on the Tumblr Theme with `display: none` and just toggle the form visible with the JavaScript -- but that's my opinion.  You could insert it into the DOM with the script as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that function does not exist in Tumblr. What you'll need to do is check the URL of the page that you're on, which is pretty simple.

You should be able to do something like this in JavaScript:

```
var currentPath = window.location.pathname; // store current path

if( currentPath.indexOf('newsletter') ) { // check if 'newsletter' is in our path
  // add your sign up form here
}
```

Comment: Kind of an iffy solution. You may pick up unwanted post pages if they contain 'newsletter' in the slug.